# how to insert any text to any website using C# code?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have any website that has 4 textboxs

i need to insert the word "YES" to textbox number 2

how i can do it using C# winform code ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

chek out my login code:

```
HtmlElementCollection trytologin = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

    var usernameInput = (from HtmlElement input in trytologin where input.Name == "username" select input).Single();
    var passwordInput = (from HtmlElement input in trytologin where input.Name == "password" select input).Single();
    usernameInput.SetAttribute("value", "myusrname");
    passwordInput.SetAttribute("value", "mypassword");
```

Comment: of course this is just an example, you must replace the input's names with the ones on your textboxes

Comment: but i dont know the textbox name, i need to insert my text on any textbox of any websit that has 4 textboxs

Comment: you need to know the names of the textboxes... how do you spect the progrma to know who is textbox # 2????